# What is the maximum heap size of 32-bit JVM in 64-bit Windows machine?

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory

We have an java swing 32-bit application running in Windows 64 bit machine. It is a legacy application and the JVM heap memory size is set as 384 MB and initial size is 32 MB. We want to increase the memory size as our current requirement is chaning . I am able to increase the size up to 1024 MB. Still I want more memory but if I increase more than 1024 MB then JVM fails to launch. Is there any other option to achieve 2048 MB for the same application?. Below is the error. My Windows machine RAM size is 16GB. Is there any way to calculate the maximum JVM memory?

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM

Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: What about running with a 64 bit java? Byte code is agnostic of 32/64 bits.

Comment: Did yu check if your machine has more than 1024MB space available?